# Backbone.js - redirecting to deleted object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, backbone.js, routes

When I delete an object with @model.destroy method, it tries to redirect to the deleted object. How can I change the routing to redirect to root instead?

My delete method:

```
  deleteBook: (ev) ->
    @model.destroy success: ->
      router.navigate "",
        trigger: true
```

Router:

```
Router = Backbone.Router.extend(routes: 
  "": "home"
)
```

Update:

Full error:

```
GET http://localhost:3000/ 404 (Not Found) jquery.js?body=1:8707
send                                       jquery.js?body=1:8707
jQuery.extend.ajax                         jquery.js?body=1:8137
Backbone.sync                              backbone_rails_sync.js?body=1:65
_.extend.destroy                           backbone.js?body=1:428
Backbone.View.extend.deleteBook            main.js?body=1:32
jQuery.event.dispatch                      jquery.js?body=1:5096
elemData.handle
```

Update2:

My coffeescript file:

```
  $(document).ready ->
    window.Book = Backbone.Model.extend(
      urlRoot: '/books/', idAttribute: 'id'
    )


    BooksView = Backbone.View.extend(
      el: ".books"
      addOne: (model) ->
        view = new BookView(model: model)
        $("ul.books").append view.render()
    )

    Router = Backbone.Router.extend(routes: 
      "": "home"
    )

    Books = Backbone.Collection.extend(
      model: Book

      url: '/books/'
    )



    BookView = Backbone.View.extend(
      tagName: "li"
      events:
        "click .delete": "deleteBook"

      deleteBook: (ev) ->
        @model.destroy()

      render: ->
        #@$el.append('Some text <button type="button" class="delete">Delete</button>')
        title = @model.get("title")
        author = @model.get("author")
        year = @model.get("year")
        link = "books/"+@model.get("id")
        a = document.createElement('a')
        a.href = link
        show = '<a href="'+a+'">Show</a>'       
        row = title + ", " + author + ", " + year + " " + show
        $(@el).html row
        @$el.append(' <button type="button" class="delete">Delete</button>')


    )

    books = new Books()
    books.url = "books.json"
    books.fetch success: ->
      books_view = new BooksView({})
      _.each books.models, (model) ->
        books_view.addOne model
```

It looks like it does not even look at the success function as, either it tries to redirect to the path were deleted object was.

Or maybe it still references deleted object and it tries to use GET method after delete somehow?..

Comment: By default, Backbone doesnt do any kind of redirect navigation on destroy.  It wont do any navigation by default at all actually

Comment: @cpjolicoeur How can I make it redirect to root? I tried to use success function, to make navigation, but it seems it does not do anything.. Also if it shouldn't do any redirecting, what could make this redirection at all? If I delete success function, it would still redirect to deleted object for some reason.

Comment: Actually I didn't use it anywhere else. But when this started, then I tried to implemented to redirect back to the root.

Comment: @naomik Are you suggesting people are trending away from CoffeeScript?  I sincerely hope so.

Comment: I'm not sure but what might be firing that route it's the click event so try to add `ev.preventDefault()` to the handler.

Comment: @numbers1311407, yep! I'd say "a bad thing can only last so long," but then we have things like PHP and whatnot to prove me wrong.

Comment: @Andrius  Did you manage to fix this error? If so can you please post the answer? Was is related to some jquery issue?